# MongoDB schema design: Multikey Index combined with True Linking

Tags: mongodb, meteor, nosql

I am building a web app with *Meteor* — and therefore *MongoDB* — to allow users to create, manage and collaborate on calendars:

- A `user` can have many `calendars`.
- A `calendar` can be shared with / used by many `users`.
- Each `user` will have a specific `role` in a given `calendar`.
- A `calendar` contains many `posts` (but a `post` only belongs to one `calendar`).

Below is how I am thinking of designing the database, based on some research in the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/) and in this video series about [MongoDB schema design](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLffUyEIMenSnRVQGxRVphq-HelRrSIdzh).

**First**:

```
user document
  {
    _id: <ObjectId1>,
    firstName: "Mickael",
    lastName: "Jackson",
    emailAddress: "mickael.jackson@example.com",
    password: "#encrypted",
    calendars = [
      {
        _id: <ObjectId2>,
        role: "Owner"
      },
  }
```

Here, the idea is to:

- Use a `Multikey Index` for the `calendar` array, so that we can both find all the `calendars` of a `user` AND find all the `users` for a `calendar`.
- Take advantage of the access pattern of the app: a `user` will always access his `calendars` when logging in, but he will seldom look for all the `users` using one of his `calendars`...
- ... thus optimizing performance.

**Then**:

```
calendar document
  {
    _id: <ObjectId2>,
    title: "Holidays"
  }
```

**And**:

```
post document
  {
    _id: <ObjectId3>,
    calendar: calendarId,
    date: "08122015",
    time: "0930",
    focus: "news",
    format: "link",
    blogTitle: 1,
    longCopy: "This is the long copy for this post.",
    shortCopy: "Short copy.",
    link: "http://www.google.com",
    hashtag: "#weekend",
    media: "image.png",
    promotion: "50",
    target: "Los Angeles",
    approval: "Ok",
    comment: "No comment"
  }
```

Here, the idea is to:

- Take advantage of the fact that a `calendar` `title` is not supposed to change often, although it can change if necessary.
- Keep `posts` in a separate collection, through `true linking`, since posts are heavy (lots of information, including media items) and would exceed the 16Mb limit of *MongoDB* documents if embedded into `calendars`.
- Allow users to CRUD `posts`, without writing into the `calendars` or into their `profile` each time...
- ... thus optimizing performance.

I am not very experimented with MongoDB and I am wondering:

- Does this approach makes sense?
- Can we actually combine a Multikey index with true linking?
- Is there a better way of achieving my goal?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what exacty you're trying to optimize. What is your goal/Quel est vôtre but?

Comment: Well, I come from the relational DB world, and need to implement a many-to-many relationship in MongoDB. So, I have done some research on the topic and came up with the solution presented in my question, and I would like to have the opinion of more experienced programmers to make sure I am not (unwillingly) violating some basic NoSQL rules. Does that make more sense? I am happy to update my question.

Comment: I think your approach will work well assuming the number of calendars each user subscribes to remains fairly small (O(100) or less). If users subscribe to 1000s or millions of calendars then you'd probably want to introduce a *calendarSubscriptions* collection. You also want to make sure that the *calendars* array can only be modified by trusted code since otherwise a user could easily make themselves owners of any calendar they subscribe to.